# systemd java file service managment

Tags: java, linux, systemd

I have this java file, it has to be executed using the following command otherwise it defaults to ipv6 and effectively useless for my use-case

```
-jar Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true EdOwl-Springboot.jar
```

I tried following this guide: https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-run-java-jar-application-with-systemd-on-linux/

However using this shows:

```
root@edowl:~# systemctl status EdOwl-Springboot.service
● EdOwl-Springboot.service - EdowlSpringboot
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/EdOwl-Springboot.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-02-22 11:28:26 UTC; 10s ago
   Main PID: 186854 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 614)
     Memory: 0B
     CGroup: /system.slice/EdOwl-Springboot.service

Feb 22 11:28:36 edowl.online systemd[1]: EdOwl-Springboot.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 125919.
Feb 22 11:28:36 edowl.online systemd[1]: Stopped EdowlSpringboot.
Feb 22 11:28:36 edowl.online systemd[1]: Started EdowlSpringboot.
Feb 22 11:28:36 edowl.online systemd[186888]: EdOwl-Springboot.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Feb 22 11:28:36 edowl.online systemd[186888]: EdOwl-Springboot.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /bin/java: No such file or directory
Feb 22 11:28:36 edowl.online systemd[1]: EdOwl-Springboot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Feb 22 11:28:36 edowl.online systemd[1]: EdOwl-Springboot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

the service file is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=EdowlSpringboot

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home
ExecStart=/bin/java -Xms128m -Xmx256m -jar Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true EdOwl-Springboot.jar
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The file is located in the `/home` dir

I am certain it is the exec start line that is messing this up, is it necessary to state: `/bin/java -Xms128m -Xmx256m`or am I messing up something else here?

Suggestions are welcome cheers

Comment: are you sure that `/bin/java` is correct? It's often present under `/usr/bin/java`.

Comment: You are missing `-` in `Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JVM argument `java.net.preferIPv4Stack` should be prefixed with `-D` instead you have `D`

Also, as others pointed out in comments check your java path it might be `/usr/bin/java`.

So, change the command to `/usr/bin/java -Xms128m -Xmx256m -jar -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true EdOwl-Springboot.jar`

Comment: Yea rookie mistake im not sure how that one slipped by me.

Also the other suggestion was key ```/usr/bin/java``` to fix it too

Cheers

Comment: Although this is correct, I am pretty sure that the error "Failed at step EXEC spawning /bin/java: No such file or directory" is not caused by the missing "-".

Comment: I got an issue report from a user who also had /bin/java (which broke our startup script!) — did something change in debian that they now install /bin/java?